# How to rename all files named a*.cpp to b*.c in current folder and subfolders in linux?

Tags: linux, centos, command, rename

The character `*` means zero or more characters.
I have tried this solution shown below:

```
find . -name 'a*.cpp' | xargs -n1 -I {} mv {} `echo {} | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/a/\1\/b/g' -e 's/cpp$/c/g'`
```

but the script in `` `...` `` seems to not work. The output on Centos 7 is:

```
mv: './folder1/ajkjk.cpp' and './folder1/ajkjk.cpp' are the same file
mv: './folder1/a.cpp' and './folder1/a.cpp' are the same file
mv: './ahhh.cpp' and './ahhh.cpp' are the same file
mv: './a.cpp' and './a.cpp' are the same file
```

Comment: add all related code to the question itself - much easier to read than in a comment

Comment: @artm thank you for your tip. It's my first time to ask in stack overflow, so I am not familiar with it.